# Error when SQL query called from C program

Tags: mysql, c

I want to execute `SOURCE data/keyw.sql` from C program. This query works fine when I execute from the command line but gives the following error on executing `mysql_query(con, "SOURCE data/keyw.sql")`

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SOURCE data/keyw.sql' at line 1

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SOURCE` command is not executed on the MySQL server.  It is interpreted by the mysql Client, and is basically just a convenience.

Quote from [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html):

> [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html) sends each SQL statement that you issue to the server to be executed. There is also a set of commands that [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html) itself interprets. For a list of these commands, type `help` or `\h` at the `mysql>` prompt:

Note that `source` is one of those listed.  If you want to know how it works, then have a look at the source code for the mysql Client.

If your source to be executed contains more than one MySQL statement then your connection will need to support [multiple statement execution](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html), or alternatively you need to parse the SQL into individual statements yourself.